# Create HttpServletRequest with session

Tags: java, spring, maven, httpsession

I'm trying to coverage my spring application and I found some problems. The principal one its to create a new `HttpServletRequest` and set session to get and set attributes (to coverage all lines of my code). This tests will run automatically with JUnit throwing by Maven, then i haven't request not response.

I'm looking for this and i found the Mockito API that brings us a way to create `HttpServletRequest` objects but i can't set a session to that object:

```
HttpServletRequest req = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you are using Spring use a `MockHttpServletRequest` which is easier then trying to mock everything with Mockito. Or even better use the Spring MockMvc support to write your tests.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it.

Comment: I'd also point out that the business logic under test shouldn't rely on any servlet spec artifacts; at best the only reason you should need a mock request is to test your marshalling logic that calls business logic. Once you've done that, you might find an integration test is more suitable for the web layer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. The comment of @M. Denium is right, but take warning on the Spring version. At the first attempt, I imported the `MockHttpServletRequest` of the `spring-mock` library, and i got a `NoSuchMethodError`. It's about the Spring version, `spring-mock` is for Spring 1 and 2. For Spring 3 or 4, use the `spring-test library`, it will work.